# Find all regions formed by a set of circles

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I was [doodling with Python to draw some circles](https://github.com/JulienPalard/circles-doodling), and I was able to find all intersection points of a set of random circles, yay !

[image]

Now I'm stuck on a question, is there a way to find all regions formed by those random set of circles ?

I'm aware of the "flood fill" algorithm, thay may almost work. But here, the drawing is just a "visual representation" of the reality, where circles have no "border width", so the flood fill may not be able to spot tiny regions completly covered by circle borders.

Also, I think that finding regions and finding intersections may be bound, as we may consider two region not being contiguous if they only touch by a intersection point.